# Get Manufacturer name for my RAM (WMI didn't get this information)

Tags: c#

I need to get the full information about RAM modules. I tried to get it by using an WMI:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher12 =
    new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2",
    "SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMemory");

            Console.WriteLine("------------- Win32_PhysicalMemory instance --------");
            foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher12.Get())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("BankLabel: {0} ; Capacity: {1} Gb; Speed: {2}; Manufacturer: {3}; Serial Number: {4}", queryObj["BankLabel"],
                                  Math.Round(System.Convert.ToDouble(queryObj["Capacity"]) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024, 2),
                                   queryObj["Speed"], queryObj["Manufacturer"], queryObj["Name"]);
            }
```

but it didn't help me, it simply doesn't have this information. How can I get this information?

Comment: This code is working for me, or at least there is an value in `queryObj["Manufacturer"]` (just a hex string though). What result are you getting in that entry?

Comment: It shows just a blank  space:http://screenshot.su/img/64/b7/b1/64b7b10e92478a5dbdd25a6586d99d60.jpg

Comment: Your machine manufacturer needs to supply the underlying chipset driver that makes this query work.  The odds they did a good job of it is roughly proportional to how much you paid for it.

Comment: Your question has been answered here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70221789/4483395

Answer (score 0):

The above code works on Windows 10.  I copied and pasted the above code into a console application.

I had to add a reference to System.Management.

When I run it I get the following output:

```
------------- Win32_PhysicalMemory instance --------
BankLabel: BANK 0 ; Capacity: 4 Gb; Speed: 1333; Manufacturer: Hynix; Serial Number: Physical Memory
BankLabel: BANK 1 ; Capacity: 4 Gb; Speed: 1333; Manufacturer: Unknown; Serial Number: Physical Memory
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code as below :

```
using System.Management;

ObjectQuery wql = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wql);
ManagementObjectCollection results = searcher.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Total Visible Memory: {0} KB", result["TotalVisibleMemorySize"]);
    Console.WriteLine("Free Physical Memory: {0} KB", result["FreePhysicalMemory"]);
    Console.WriteLine("Total Virtual Memory: {0} KB", result["TotalVirtualMemorySize"]);
    Console.WriteLine("Free Virtual Memory: {0} KB", result["FreeVirtualMemory"]);
}
```

and the output is :

```
Total Visible Memory: 16617056 KB
Free Physical Memory: 2465396 KB
Total Virtual Memory: 35511496 KB
Free Virtual Memory: 4005632 KB
```