# Get RAM Manufacturer & PartNumber

Tags: c#, windows

Like in this question [Get Manufacturer name for my RAM (WMI didn't get this information)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41047307), i need to get the manufacturer and partnumber.

The following solutions don't work:

```bash
Get-WmiObject -class Win32_PhysicalMemory | Format-Table Manufacturer, PartNumber
```

```cs
using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMemory"))
{
    using (ManagementObjectCollection data = searcher.Get())
    {
        foreach (ManagementObject obj in data)
        {
            string manufacturer = obj.GetPropertyValue("Manufacturer")?.ToString().Trim();
            string memType = MemoryType(Convert.ToInt32(obj.GetPropertyValue("MemoryType")));
            string part = obj.GetPropertyValue("PartNumber").ToString().Trim();
            string size = obj.GetPropertyValue("Capacity").ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

In both solutions, Manufacturer & PartNumber are empty.
On the other hand, with Aida64, the complete information of the ram does come out.

Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC v10.0 (17763)

Samsung DDR3 99U5403-002.A00LF 2GB

#### From the proposed solutions.

[image: wmic-query-results]

[image: wmic-query2]

Comment: Compiling directly to X64 didn't work either. It keeps returning empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

`Powershell WMIC Memorychip` command does in fact have the manufacturer and serial number in it, however, it is encrypted data.

From a `CMD` or `PowerShell` Window:

`wmic memorychip get manufacturer`,
`wmic memorychip get serialnumber`

These are the relevant `PowerShell WMIC` Commands, where the `GET` suffix retrieves the specific data from the specific header.

`WMIC MEMCACHE`,
`WMIC MEMORYCHIP`,
`WMIC MEMPHYSICAL`

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ztwZ.png)

I am curious if anyone knows how to convert the ID's into a company name as well! Hope this is helpful!

Comment: A BIOS/UEFI update may be available that updates this information.

Comment: According to [this documentation](https://www.mikrocontroller.net/attachment/39268/jep106k.pdf), `7F` is a continuation code - which occurs three times. After that we see `0B`. If we add spaces to make it easier to read, we have `7F 7F 7F 0B` - which shows that the manufacturer code (`0B`) is in "bank four". According to the previously referenced document the manufacturer is "Nanya Technology".

Comment: This doesn't work either, what it returns are empty strings. Look at the screenshot I added with the query to the wmic.

Answer (score 0):

The following shows how to retrieve memory and OS information using WMI.

Create a class (name: helper)

```
//Add reference:
//Project => Add Reference => Assemblies => System.Management
//add using statement: using System.Management;

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Management;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace GetSystemInfo
{
    public class Helper
    {
        public static string GetSystemInfo()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            sb.AppendFormat("{0}{1}", GetOSInfo(), System.Environment.NewLine);
            sb.AppendFormat("{0}{1}", GetMemoryInfo(), System.Environment.NewLine);

            return sb.ToString();
        }

        public static string GetOSInfo()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM WIN32_OperatingSystem"))
            {
                using (ManagementObjectCollection mObjCollection = searcher.Get())
                {
                    foreach (ManagementBaseObject mbObj in mObjCollection)
                    {
                        //if null, go to next iteration
                        if (mbObj == null)
                            continue;

                        string caption = mbObj.GetPropertyValue("Caption")?.ToString().Trim();
                        string version = mbObj.GetPropertyValue("version").ToString().Trim();
                        string versionMinor = version.Contains(".") ? version.Substring(version.LastIndexOf(".") + 1) : string.Empty;
                        string versionMajor = version.Contains(".") ? version.Substring(0, version.LastIndexOf(".")) : string.Empty;

                        sb.AppendFormat("{0}", caption);

                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(versionMajor))
                            sb.AppendFormat(" v {0}", versionMajor);

                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(versionMinor))
                            sb.AppendFormat(" ({0})", versionMinor);

                        sb.AppendFormat("{0}", System.Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                }

                return sb.ToString();
            }
        }

        public static string GetMemoryInfo()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM WIN32_PhysicalMemory"))
            {
                using (ManagementObjectCollection mObjCollection = searcher.Get())
                {
                    foreach (ManagementBaseObject mbObj in mObjCollection)
                    {
                        //if null, go to next iteration
                        if (mbObj == null)
                            continue;

                        string manufacturer = mbObj.GetPropertyValue("Manufacturer")?.ToString().Trim();
                        string memType = MemoryType(Convert.ToInt32(mbObj.GetPropertyValue("MemoryType")));
                        string part = mbObj.GetPropertyValue("PartNumber").ToString().Trim();
                        string size = MemorySize(Convert.ToDouble(mbObj.GetPropertyValue("Capacity")));

                        sb.AppendFormat("{0} {1} {2} {3}{4}", manufacturer, memType, part, size, System.Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                }

                return sb.ToString();
            }
        }

        private static string MemorySize(double memSize)
        {
            string result = String.Format("{0} bytes", memSize.ToString());

            double sizeInTB = memSize / 1024.0 / 1024.0 / 1024.0 / 1024.0;
            double sizeInGB = memSize / 1024.0 / 1024.0 / 1024.0;
            double sizeInMB = memSize / 1024.0 / 1024.0;
            double sizeInKB = memSize / 1024.0;

            Debug.WriteLine("sizeInTB: " + sizeInTB);
            Debug.WriteLine("sizeInGB: " + sizeInGB);
            Debug.WriteLine("sizeInMB: " + sizeInMB);

            if (sizeInTB > 1.0)
                return String.Format("{0} TB", sizeInTB);
            else if (sizeInGB > 1.0)
                return String.Format("{0} GB", sizeInGB);
            else if (sizeInMB > 1.0)
                return String.Format("{0} GB", sizeInMB);
            else if (sizeInKB > 1.0)
                return String.Format("{0} KB", sizeInGB);
          
            return result;
        }

        private static string MemoryType(int memType)
        {
            string result = string.Empty;

            switch (memType)
            {
                case 0:
                    return "Unknown";
                case 1:
                    return "Other";
                case 2:
                    return "DRAM";
                case 3:
                    return "Synchronous DRAM";
                case 4:
                    return "Cache DRAM";
                case 5:
                    return "EDO";
                case 6:
                    return "EDRAM";
                case 7:
                    return "VRAM";
                case 8:
                    return "SRAM";
                case 9:
                    return "RAM";
                case 10:
                    return "ROM";
                case 11:
                    return "Flash";
                case 12:
                    return "EEPROM";
                case 13:
                    return "FEPROM";
                case 14:
                    return "EPROM";
                case 15:
                    return "CDRAM";
                case 16:
                    return "3DRAM";
                case 17:
                    return "SDRAM";
                case 18:
                    return "SGRAM";
                case 19:
                    return "RDRAM";
                case 20:
                    return "DDR";
                case 21:
                    return "DDR2";
                case 22:
                    return "DDR2 FB-DIMM";
                case 24:
                    return "DDR3";
                case 26:
                    return "DDR4";
                default:
                    return "not specified";    
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
string output = Helper.GetSystemInfo();
```

**Resources**:

- [Win32_PhysicalMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-physicalmemory)
- [Win32_OperatingSystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-operatingsystem)

Comment: This doesn't work either, what it returns are empty strings. I've seen many PCs where it works, but not on this one. 
Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. H55M-S2H 
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU 650 @ 3.20GHz

Comment: Check that the `Windows Management Instrumentation` service is running. From a cmd window: `sc query winmgmt | find /i "state"` . Alternatively, Control Panel (View By: Small Icons) => Administrative Tools => Services => Windows Management Instrumentation (it should be set to start automatically). See [Starting and Stopping the WMI Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/starting-and-stopping-the-wmi-service) for more information.

Comment: Yes, it is running

Comment: What do you get by running `wmic memorychip get manufacturer, banklabel, capacity` from a cmd window? If no results, try opening a cmd window as Administrator.

Comment: look at the latest edition

Comment: The following may be helpful: [Rebuild the WMI Repository](https://www.blesk.ca/rebuild-the-wmi-repository/), [How to repair or rebuild the WMI Repository on Windows 11/10](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-repair-or-rebuild-the-wmi-repository-on-windows-10), [Repair a Windows Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/repair-a-windows-image?view=windows-11) and https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-dism-command-line-utility-repair-windows-10-image

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

You can use the below code to find the Manufacturer and Part Number of Physical Memory of your system:

```
using System;
using System.Management;

namespace GetRAM
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ManagementScope oMs = new ManagementScope();
            ObjectQuery oQuery = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMemory");
            ManagementObjectSearcher oSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(oMs, oQuery);
            ManagementObjectCollection oCollection = oSearcher.Get();

            foreach (ManagementObject obj in oCollection)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Manufacturer: {obj["Manufacturer"]} | Part Number: {obj["PartNumber"]}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use the below command in Command Prompt to get the details:

```
wmic MEMORYCHIP get Manufacturer, PartNumber
```

**Results:**

[image]

**Method 2**

```
$colRAM = Get-WmiObject -Class "win32_PhysicalMemory" -namespace "root\CIMV2" `

Foreach ($objRAM In $colRAM) {
     "Manufacturer: " + $objRAM.Manufacturer
     "PartNumber: " + $objRAM.PartNumber
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: This is a duplicate answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41047307/get-manufacturer-name-for-my-ram-wmi-didnt-get-this-information

Comment: Sorry for that! I'll take care next time.

Comment: This doesn't work either, what it returns are empty strings. Look at the screenshot I added with the query to the wmic.

Comment: @Ernesto Could you please try Method 2 in my updated answer.